# When tap on cancel button, which is delegate method called for Sharing Option using UIActivityViewController

Tags: uiactivityviewcontroller

When tap on cancel button, which is delegate method called? Please look into the below image. Sharing Option using UIActivityViewController

Comment: No image attached. But i think nutz answer will solve your problem.

Answer (score 6):

`UIActivityViewControllerCompletionHandler`
A completion handler to execute after the activity view controller is dismissed.

`typedef void (^UIActivityViewControllerCompletionHandler)(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed);`

You can access it as below:

```
[activityViewControllerObj setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed) {
    NSLog(@"completed"); 
}];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSArray * shareItems = @[message, image];
UIActivityViewController * avc = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:shareItems applicationActivities:nil];
[avc setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed) {
    //finish your code when the user finish or dismiss...
    if (completed) {
        NSLog(@"avc done");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"avc cancelled"); //<<<<---
    }
}];
[self presentViewController:avc animated:YES completion:nil];
```